# Visual Composer row position fixed

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

i need help to make a row position fixed in WP Visual Composer or even better to stick it below the fixed header via css. i see

```
.call_to1 {position: fixed}
```

is not working.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to do a quick fix using !important .

```
  .call_to1 {position: fixed !important}
```

Comment: hello. thanks for the answer. it somehow fixes it, but when the position is fixed the row is not full width anymore. because by default the row has position: relative. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: what is your row class name?
for example :
.youtrowclassname{width: 100% !important; position: fixed !important;}